# Test for innerHTML of a div

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement, innerhtml, slot

this is my first time asking a question. I am trying to make a program where there are slots that act like an inventory (you know what I'm talking about if you've played Minecraft), as shown below. I also have a table which is like a shop.

```
 <p><b>Money:</b></p>
<p id="moneytext">$5500</p>

<p><b>Weapons:</b></p>

<table style="width:140px">

    <tr>
        <td onclick="myFunction()">Dagger</td>
        <td>$50</td>
    <tr>
        <td onclick="myFunction2()">Battle Axe</td>
        <td>$300</td>
    </tr>
    <td onclick="myFunction3()">Bow</td>
    <td>$500</td>
    <tr>
        <td onclick="myFunction4()">Crossbow</td>
        <td>$700</td>
    <tr>
        <td onclick="getSword()">Sword</td>
        <td>$1,000</td>
    </tr>

</table>

 <table>
    <tr>

        <td>
            <div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
        </td>

        <td>
            <div id="div2" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
        </td>

        <td>
            <div id="div3" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>

        </td>

        <td>
            <div id="div4" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
        </td>

        <td>
            <div id="div5" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
        </td>

    </tr>
</table>
```

When you click the sword it gives you a sword image in your inventory.

```
function minusAnyNumber(minusNumber) {
    money = money - minusNumber;
    document.getElementById("moneytext").innerHTML = "$" + money;
}

function getSword() {
    if (money >= 1000) {
        checkInventory4Sword();
        minusAnyNumber(minus1000);
    }
}
```

Now I want to check if there's a sword in the first slot. If there isn't I place a sword there. If there is a sword there already, I place it in the second slot.

```
var div1iHTML = document.getElementById("div1").innerHTML;
var div2iHTML = document.getElementById("div2").innerHTML;
var divoccupied = '<img src="http://www.rw-designer.com/icon-view/5542.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="drag1" width="20" height="20">';

function checkInventory4Sword()
{
    if (div1iHTML == divoccupied)
    { div2Place(); }
else (document.getElementById("div1").innerHTML = '<img src="http://www.rw-designer.com/icon-view/5542.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="drag1" width="20" height="20">');
}

function div2Place()
{
    document.getElementById("div2").innerHTML = '<img src="http://www.rw-designer.com/icon-view/5542.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="drag1" width="20" height="20">';
}
```

It never executes the if statement no matter what I change in it and gives me the sword into the first slot all the time. I had a sword placed in the second slot a few times too, when there wasn't a sword in the first slot. I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Can you please tell me?

Comment: When and where do you initialize div1iHTML?  And do you ever update the value of that variable?

Comment: @StepanRiha Do I need to update the variable? Even when I used to just say-

Comment: @StepanRiha Sorry I accidently triedskipping a line and click enter. Anyway, even when I say: if(document.getElementById("div1").innerHTML = '<img src="http://www.rw-designer.com/icon-view/5542.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="drag1" width="20" height="20">';) it still doesn't work.

Comment: You don't need to update the divoccupied variable, but you do need to look at the current contents of the innerHTML.

Comment: Anyway, I would recommend that you set a breakpoint at the beginning of the checkInventory4Sword() function and then step through the code and look at the values of your variables.

Also, it will help you if you clean up your code a little.  For example you should use {} instead of () around the else assignment.

Comment: Finally, it's generally not a good idea to drive your application logic by comparing contents of innerHTML.  when you set the innerHTML property to a string, the browser will normalize it to valid HTML.

A better approach is to manage your application state separately (e.g. an inventory array) and then update the DOM based on that.

Comment: @StepanRiha Yeah, my step-dad told me about the string thing yesterday and I found out you guys were right. But how do I do this without a string? I didn't really get what you meant about application state and DOM. I'll try to find those on W3schools.

Comment: You want to separate the state (e.g. what's in the inventory) from what's being displayed.  The following link demonstrates the idea:  https://gist.github.com/nonplus/f349b0ec9357009fbb03#file-inventory